# SwipeRefreshLayout in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

I have Activity

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <FrameLayout/> // fragmentContainer
   <OtherView/>
<RelativeLayout>
```

into fragmentContainer I put Fragment with TabLayout with 3 tabs.

```
TabLayout
ViewPager
```

On every tab I use same ListFragment which looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I initalize it in PagerAdapter where I hold list of ListFragment Instances

```
FRAGMENTS: List<Fragment> = listOf(
    ListFragment.newInstance(Mode.FIRST)
    ListFragment.newInstance(Mode.SECOND)
    ListFragment.newInstance(Mode.THIRD)
)
```

Depends from mode it loads data from different source.

The problem is that Swipe Refresh works only on first two fragments.
On third there is no swipe gesture.

Comment: post your third fragment xml and java code

Comment: add your class file here

Comment: Yes I know, please give me time for this :)

Comment: I found that this is a problem with recycler view content, not with swipe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in recycler view content loaded on third tab.
First loaded item had this:

```
this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                0)
```